# how can I have a different Storyboard.strings to the same storyboard for each target in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have multiple storyboards in my project. Lets say one of them is `Main.storyboard`. I have few hard coded strings in `Main.storyboard`. Because we are trying to create a white labeled app, I have added multiple targets to existing project.

Now each target uses the same `Main.storyboard` because there is no change in UI. But I need to customize the hardcoded strings in `Main.storyboard` to each target.

For example in Target A strings should say "Welcome to A" when built for TargetB string should be "Welcome to B".

One way I can think of is creating `IBOutlet` to each such `UIComponent` and update their value dynamically by adding `if else` statements or easy way would be enable localization to `Main.storyboard` and have different `Main.strings` file for each target.

I would prefer using 2nd approach but I dont know how to achieve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. No need of code in here hence not adding any snippet. If you need screen shot of project structure lemme know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `Localizable.strings` file for each target
2. Add an entry in each `Localizable.strings` file with a common key but different text
3. Set the text with the `NSLocalizedString` function

[image: example]

**Update:**

Instead of `Localizable.strings` you could also add `Main.strings` (name depends on your storyboard name) files for each target. In those files you can then set texts for specific UI elements by using `{element_identifier}.text` as the key. You find the identifier by right clicking the storyboard -> "Open As" -> "Source Code".

[image: example 2]

Comment: This will work for strings set programmatically but I need to dynamically change the text in storyboard. This approach will not work :(

Comment: What's wrong with setting the texts programmatically?

Comment: I have lot of storyboards and many of them static text, creating IBOutlet and updating text programmatically, just replace one word in static text chunk does not make much sense. Ill end up writing loads of text, I was looking for a neater and simpler solution

Comment: Yes. As you can see on my screenshots I added my own `Main.strings` files - not the ones automatically created via localization settings.

Comment: Read About ios localization you file to find the way to localize the hardcoded string in storyboard or you can have different string files and from app delegate set that file by checking target.

Comment: @andré-slotta : tried, but did not work :( did you actually tried specifying different text in your string file and checked the OP ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Yes. For me it works. Take a look at my demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hth62lqgt39404/WhiteLabel.zip?dl=0

Comment: @andré-slotta : I wish I could give 100 upvotes :) Thanks a lot :) one word amazing answer :)

Comment: Create some more SO accounts and go for it. ;) Glad I could help!

Comment: @andré-slotta : hahahahahaha Dont worry, its a great answer so will get appreciated in future as well

Comment: This solution talks about localization of text. How exactly does it fix the problem of different targets needing to display different texts.

Comment: @AndréSlotta I read the answer. I had already figured out about the first approach you mentioned. But just like the OP, I did not want a lot of changes to existing code base. Coming to the Main.strings file, are not they generated for each language that the app support ? Sorry If i came across rude, but could not figure out the answer

Comment: No worries. The trick is to create them manually. One for each target. As mentioned in the answer.